# OCI8 + PHP7.1 + Windows10: The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, windows, oracle-call-interface

I have recently upgraded my windows from 7 to 10. After the upgrade I have "installed" PHP7.1 by adding the executable path to `PATH` environment variable, the same `php.ini` as old windows (since it is the same folder, nothing changed) and also added the same instant client 12 to the `PATH`.

Using `php -v`, it loads all the modules including mbstrings and xdebug except the oci modules stating:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP 7.1.1 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 18:38:49) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>
> with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

I also tried installing a fresh windows, getting oci again from pecl, getting instant client from OTN again. None have worked yet. I have MSVC14 redistributable installed. Windows is 64-bits, same as PHP.

Comment: Your PHP is listed as x64 - make sure that the InstantClient is too. And if I remember correctly the InstantClient requires [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) to be installed (that'll also need to be x64).

Comment: @timclutton The msvc100.dll (2010) was actually the case! thank you so much!

Comment: @timclutton It's been a long time, but it will be great if you could post your comment as an answer so it can be marked as an answer. It solved the problem.

Comment: It's never too late to post a solution 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting my own [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919265/oci8-php7-1-windows10-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found?noredirect=1#comment71046258_41919265), as [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919265/oci8-php7-1-windows10-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found?noredirect=1#comment102235756_41919265):

> Your PHP is listed as x64 - make sure that the InstantClient is too. And if I remember correctly the InstantClient requires [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) to be installed (that'll also need to be x64).